# Installing Support library for Material Design

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

Using SDK Manager I downloaded the Support Library to use Material Design for previous versions.

Now the question is, how do I use this in my Android Studio project? Specifically if I want Material Design?

Here is my *gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "obx.com.futurister"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following dependencies to the build.gradle file of your module.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```

Comment: Thanks, So does this enable to use all Material design features? :)

Comment: yes. this will enable all Material design features supported by Support library. Please go through [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) blog

Comment: @silwar cardview is not needed.

Comment: May be 23.0.1 is better than 22.2.1

Answer (score 1):

just add this on depedencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

hope it help

Answer (score 1):

Android studio 1.4 has many new templates that use the material design support library. I highly recommend downloading it! Otherwise, you can do it as follows:

## build.gradle should contain

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```

## main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="company.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_activity" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## content_main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context="company.MainActivity"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## And in your onCreate method in MainActivity.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);    

        toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Your imports should include:

- `import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;`
- `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`
- `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

And MainActivity should extend AppCompatActivity
And your main activity theme in styles.xml should include

- `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`
- `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`
- `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>`
- `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Hope that helps! Comment if you have a further question! Otherwise have a nice day!

Comment: You should use the v23.0.1. Also the design library is enough.

Comment: Oh? Does it contain all three of the others? Also yes, `v23.0.1` if it is configured for your app, however mine isn't so that's just what I copied and pasted. So for some yes, otherwise `22.2.1` will suffice.

Comment: It has a dependency with Appcompat.

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't include the card view or Recycler view?

Comment: No it doesn't contain them.

Comment: Okay, then yea, I was saying that those two are fairly necessary for most cases of Material Design.

Comment: Well of course you can use it, but I in a strict way , the recyclerview is not related to material design.

Comment: Okay, well whatever, I would disagree as it was released **with** material design, but it really doesn't matter, so thank you.